# Can I pair an iPhone 4S to Apple TV?

Tags: iphone, appletv

Can I pair an iPhone 4S to Apple TV (no longer activated with Verizon) or can I connect the iPhone **directly** to Apple TV to get an HDMI output?

Comment: Define "pair". If you mean stream videos and music to it, then yes, you can definitely do that. It's called Airplay and you access it in Control Center.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that is impossible. But, you can use the Lightning to HDMI adapter or AirPlay to an Apple TV.